# How to locate .php code and file on the server when inspecting elements from an internet browser?

Tags: php, browser, firebug, inspect

When I inspect an element of my webpage using Firebug, I cannot identify which .php code it using and on which php file I can find this code on from the server. Is there any other way to locate pieces of php codes from a browser?

Many thanks,

Arthur

Comment: what do you mean by "php page"?

Comment: your php dynamically generates html for browser. So firebug on ff can only see the generated html.

Comment: if your are including multiple php files, you need to print comments as to where includes start and stop. you could also check out firephp.

Comment: I mean the .PHP file which is on the server of my website, I would like to locate it from the browser directly.

Comment: Unless your web server provides with such a capacity, you can't

Comment: Thanks ldg and Sheen, I will look into firephp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could edit the source code to make print out. Maybe a HTML comment such as:`<!-- Start of index.php -->`

I actively work to hide what PHP-file is used to generate any specific HTML-output as it makes out a **serious security threat**.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the address bar of the browser. Firebug inspect works for the current browser page and it doesn't know what PHP is - it's just HTML content, regardless of the script running on the server that generated the content.

If this doesn't help, elaborate your question.

Comment: Thanks Veseliq, how can I identify the specific .PHP file to modify on my server?

Comment: This is impossible to know without more details. I would go by doing simple text search on the files on your server for snippets of HTML that is unlikely to be dynamic like '<div class="profile">' to look up where the HTML near that div is generated. BUT this is totally shooting directions - no way to know what your server system is, how it generates content and firebug can not help you at all.

Comment: Look at the address bar, that will tell you which file the page you are looking at was loaded from... What exactly are you trying to modify? I think you're asking wrong question to be honest - it's not 'how do I find it in Firebug', but 'how do I find the bit of PHP code that does XXX'

Answer (score 0):

If this were possible it would make php less secure, a part of the security is the obscurity, if you could simple find out which file does what it would be much easer to launch a targeted attack.